# Configure server-side CORS: ExpressJS No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

Very simple, just trying to complete a CORS request to a basic ExpressJS server. Haven't had much experience dealing with ExpressJS before, but having been through a few similar questions, I can't see the problem. It looks as though I haven't added the required headers in the right place, as the Chrome error indicates there's nothing there.

```
app.configure = function () {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        next();
    })
}
```

Is this code not correct? Have I got client-side and server-side code mixed up? Also, the server is mine, so I'm trying to make sure that the server can respond correctly to CORS requests, rather than use a proxy to fool it.

Comment: please also show the client configuration, and tell if you are sending some custom headers, because that affect the config of your CORS

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the express version you are using, app.configure might not be available anymore.

So you should use it directly like that :

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        next();
 })
```

Or as written on the documentation, if you want to setup multiple headers

```
res.set({
 'header1' : 'Foobar',
 'header2' : 'Foobar'
});
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that I had it formatted like that originally, but no dice.